# is overriding onActivityResult mandatory after startActivityForResult

Tags: android

can I call `startActivityForResult` then return a result from activity, and when Im back in the first activity, can I not override `onActivityResult`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not *mandatory*, but calling `startActivityForResult()` only makes sense if you are also calling `onActivityResult()`. The two are meant to be used in conjunction to receive callbacks on completion of tasks. Or else you could just call `startActivity()`.

Comment: The matter is, Im doing `getActivity().startActivityForResult` from a fragment that could be used in either one of total of 3 activities, and I only need `onActivityResult` in one of them :) Thank you

Comment: `if you are also calling onActivityResult()`. Please rephrase. One does not call onActivityResult(). It is called by the OS if the programmer has overridden/implemented it.